# JsonMappingException (was java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, jackson, idml

I've been searching for this for a while but haven't found any answers, so either I'm missing something so obvious noone has written anything about it, or I've hit an unusual problem. I'm hoping it's the first...

I'm working with a third-party library ([IDMLlib](http://idmllib.com)) to extract information from an Adobe InDesign document stored in the .idml format. The contents are easily read and stored in an object of type "Idml", which contains everything I need. Now, I want to send this object to a web client (browser) using [Jackson JSON](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

I've hit 2 problems:

1) The object tree is full of circular referefences. I've fixed this by using Mix-ins with the annotation

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
```

So now I've got a lot of Mix-ins ready, if needed for problem 2.

2) I keep getting new object-specific errors when serializing.

```
--Output from testMethodsReturnsSomething--
| Failure:  testMethods(package.IdmlServiceTests)
|  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: de.fhcon.idmllib.api.elements.Idml["document"]->de.fhcon.idmllib.api.elements.Document["tags"]->de.fhcon.idmllib.api.elements.tags.Tags["xmltagList"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->de.fhcon.idmllib.api.elements.tags.XMLTag["tagColor"]->de.fhcon.idmllib.api.elements.typedefs.InDesignUIColorType["greenValue"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:218)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:183)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:155)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:533)
...
```

I've tried writing a custom NullValue/NullKey serializer, but that doesn't help the NullPointerException.

Is there an annotation I can use in my Mix-ins that handles this?
Or is there another way for me to serialize this object?

Comment: Alas, what is really needed is the part of stack trace closer to original NPE. This part just points to catch clause that rethrows a `RuntimeException`. Without knowing that, it is not possible to say what to do to avoid it.

Comment: Turns out the attribute "greenValue" is of type Double, not double, so it can also have the value null. While Double can handle null values, double can't. My theory is that Jackson JSON tries to access it as a primitive datatype, causing the crash. Still not sure what to do about it, though...

Comment: This sounds like possible bug in handling, so it'd be good to file a bug for Jackson. While most handlers for primitive types do coerce nulls into default value (0.0d here), perhaps Object Id handler does not take proper precaution -- or maybe setter/field access triggers the issue. Java does automatic unwrapping in many cases.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are right, `Double` can handle *null* value, and `double` can't.
In my case, my property was of type `Long` but the getter was returning a `long` value and not a `Long` value. This was acceptable as far as the value was not *null*. But when the value was *null*, jackson was not able to serialize the *null* value for `long`.

Just changing the getter to return a `Long` instead of a `long` fixed it.
Verify if your getter return a `Double` and not a `double` in your case.

ps: I know this question is quite old but since I was having the same problem and the question was 2nd in Google answers... Seemed fair to answer it later than never

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I have faced same issue when I tried to marshall an object containing Boolean value as attribute , but turned that I had returned boolean in its getter method.
Just changing the getter method's return type to Boolean fixed the issue,

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is still valid but, I solved this problem by changing the version of `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml`. Earlier I was using 2.3.0 and was getting this same error. I changed it to 2.7.8 and it is working fine now.

Comment: Thank you, it really help me!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue after upgrading to spring boot 2.4.1 from 1.5, issue is one of the field is not getting serialized while invoking a GET Request. Earlier the piece of code looks like below (before spring boot upgrade)

```
@Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer getRestConfigurer() {
        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            void configureJacksonObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
                super.configureJacksonObjectMapper(objectMapper)
                def validationResponseSerializerUtil = new ValidationResponseSerializerUtil()
                def simpleModule = validationResponseSerializerUtil.getSerializeModule()
                objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule)
                objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
            }
        }
    }
```

But after spring boot upgrade, above piece of code (serializing the ValidationResponse via RepositoryRestConfigurer) is not working, replaced it with below

```
@Bean(name = "objectMapper")
    ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        def validationResponseSerializerUtil = new ValidationResponseSerializerUtil()
        def simpleModule = validationResponseSerializerUtil.getSerializeModule()
        ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper()
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule)
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
        return objectMapper
    }
```

Now everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a NullPointerException on a class where I had tagged the constructors with @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator.  When I removed the tag, deserialization json -> mojo worked.

Answer (score 0):

Always check before conversion:-

`if(node.get("id")!=null) { int id = (Integer) ((IntNode)node.get("id")).numberValue();}`

It may be possible that your json may not contain any key. Then it will throw null pointer exception. So better to check for null first.