# JacksonMapping Exception :: HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: (was java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: mysql, json, spring, jackson

- Framework Spring MVC 4.x
- Hibernate 4.x
- Jackson 2.8

I have two columns one is `publishDate` and `createdDate`.  Publish date user need to manually enter it.  Created date in MySQL column has a default set as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so when an entry is created DB will automatically timestamp the entry.

I have a book POJO `publishDate` and `createdDate` field... `publishDate` can handle null data for some reason. But Timestamp field gets an exception.  Why is this?

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not 
write content: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: 
java.util.HashMap["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[30]-
>com.app.books.Book["dateCreated"]); nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was 
java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: 
java.util.HashMap["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[30]-
>com.app.books.Book["dateCreated"])
```

I tried to suppress this by adding annotation, I tried several of them because I keep reading conflicting info on the comments section on which to use.

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL) // but show JsonSerialize is deprecated

@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)// Include can not be resolved as variable

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT) // finally doesn't give me an error but I still get the same exception.
```

This is my book Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
@Component
public class Book implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2042607611480064259L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

@NotBlank
private String name;

@NotBlank
@Size(min=2, max=16)
private String ispn;

@DecimalMin(value = "0.1")
private double price;

//@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
//@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
//@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
private Timestamp dateCreated;

private Date datePublished;
```

Very wried... Thanks for helping..

Answer (score 0):

You may have better results switching from primitives (int & double) to Java classes (Int & Double) in your Book class.  See [JsonMappingException (was java.lang.NullPointerException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779278/jsonmappingexception-was-java-lang-nullpointerexception) also [JSON: JsonMappingException while try to deserialize object with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096589/json-jsonmappingexception-while-try-to-deserialize-object-with-null-values)